# How do I get a twitter feed via a "username" query?

Tags: twitter-feed

I currently have the following URL but it searchs for a keyword rather than just the users feed.

> http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from%3AUSERNAME

I want my users to be able to provide there username only and a feed be displayed on their profile.

What url should i use to obtain a users feed including old posts?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/%USERID%.rss
```

Where %USERID% is the ID of the user in question.

For example, the url to my own timeline is:

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/16979198.rss
```

with 16979198 being my user id number.

**UPDATE**

According to the Twitter API, you can also do the same with the users username as follows:

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/%USERNAME%.rss
```

Where %USERNAME% is the username of the person who's feed you'd like to view.

For example:

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/jamiedixon.rss
```

You can also replace the `.rss` portion of the link with other data types such as `.json` `.atom`

For further information on the Twitter API and Timelines, visit here:

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-statuses-user_timeline

Comment: I'm aware of that one but i dont think many people know there id and id prefer if they can use there username , or is that not a good idea?  Thanks in advance

Comment: legend :) was hoping it would be that easy just everywhere i've looked it related to the users id / number!!  Cheers fella

Comment: It doesn't have to be their UID, their username works as well.

Comment: Tried and tested. I;m using it along with magpie rss. Works a treat. 
@Jamie +1 chappy :)

Comment: THIS SOLUTION DOES NOT WORK ANYMORE AS TWITTER RETURNS 404 ERROR.